# Windows Mobile, Silverlight - Controls are NOT placed on the screen where I want them to be placed

Tags: silverlight, mobile

Quick question, if I may.

Basically, I have a method which throws images on to the screen. But....The images don't get placed when I want them to.

This is the code:

```
leafArray[0].Margin = new Thickness(0, 32, 0, 0);
leafArray[1].Margin = new Thickness(109, 32, 0, 0);
leafArray[2].Margin = new Thickness(204, 32, 0, 0);
leafArray[3].Margin = new Thickness(240, 32, 0, 0);
leafArray[4].Margin = new Thickness(309, 32, 0, 0);
leafArray[5].Margin = new Thickness(446, 32, 0, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < leafArray.Length; i++)
   {
     LayoutRoot.Children.Add(leafArray[i]);
   }
```

Now....the images DO show on the emulator...but they are not where I told them to be! Rather, that are always on the top right hand side...It's almost as if they are placing themselves there because there is a container there. Which there obviously isn't! I only have a single panel...RootPanel.

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could you also post the XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Canvas instead of Grid.
And before showing your image try this

```
Canvas.SetTop(this.leafArray[0],32);
Canvas.SetLeft(this.leafArray[0],0);
Canvas.SetTop(this.leafArray[1],32);
Canvas.SetLeft(this.leafArray[1],109);
...

for (int i = 0; i < leafArray.Length; i++)
{
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(leafArray[i]);
}
```

Your LayoutRoot has to be a  Canvas on the XAML code

Comment: Ok...When I do:    Canvas.SetLeft(leafArray[0], 1);
            Canvas.SetTop(leafArray[0], 32);    It gives me a NullReferenceException and it points towards the code above. How can I fix this? It wants me to use the "new" keyword to instantiate a new object but...I'm not creating any object here....

Comment: is yor leafArray initialized when you set the position? I mean the item, not the array.